# Gorm Find Query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

**Facts**
- JDK 1.6 and Grails 2.0.0

I would like to write a groovy query in the Grails application as listed below to do something similar to the SQL below,

```
Select t.debtor, t.creditor From Transaction t, Account a where 
a.account_id = ?
```

However I am getting error

```
No property found for name [accountId] for class [class com.Transaction]
```

**Account.groovy**

```
package com

class Account {
    String name
    BigDecimal balance = 200
    String emailAddress


    static hasMany = [transactions: Transaction]

    static constraints = {
        name()
        balance()
        emailAddress()
    }

    String toString() {
        return name + " " + balance
    }
}
```

**Transaction**

```
package com

class Transaction {

    String debtor
    String creditor
    BigDecimal amount
    Date transactionDate

    static belongsTo = [account: Account]

    static constraints = {
    }

    String toString() {
        return "debtor : " + debtor + " creditor " + creditor + " £" + amount + " - transaction Date  : " + transactionDate
    }
}
```

**TransactionController.groovy**

```
def showTransactionsForAccount() {
    def accountId = params.selectedAccount
    def allTransactionsByAccountId = Transaction.findAllByAccountId(accountId)

    redirect(action: "list", model: [transactionInstance: allTransactionsByAccountId, 
        transactionInstanceTotal: allTransactionsByAccountId.count()])

}
```

**Error Stack**

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/payment-app/transaction/showTransactionsForAccount
Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException
Message
No property found for name [accountId] for class [class com.Transaction]
Around line 20 of grails-app\controllers\com\TransactionController.groovy
17:
18:    def showTransactionsForAccount() {
19:        def accountId = params.selectedAccount
20:        def allTransactionsByAccountId = Transaction.findAllByAccountId(accountId)
21:
22:        redirect(action: "list", model: [transactionInstance: allTransactionsByAccountId, 
23:            transactionInstanceTotal: allTransactionsByAccountId.count()])
Trace
   Line | Method
->> 105 | doCall                     in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    20 | showTransactionsForAccount in TransactionController.groovy
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                        in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no property named `accountId` in `Transaction` domain. Your query should be-

```
def allTransactionsByAccountId = Transaction.findAllByAccount(Account.get(accountId))
```

and I think `transactionInstanceTotal: allTransactionsByAccountId.count()` is also wrong in the controller. Should be

```
transactionInstanceTotal: Transaction.count()
```

Comment: Thanks user1690588, quite right, the first bit was useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
TransactionController.groovy
```

```
def showTransactionsForAccount() {
    def accountId = params.selectedAccount
    def allTransactionsByAccountId  = Transaction.findAllByAccount(Account.get(accountId))
    render(view: "list", model: [transactionInstanceList: allTransactionsByAccountId , transactionInstanceTotal: allTransactionsByAccountId .size()])
}
```

This is no means optimized or a best practices yet, just work in progress.